# How to move memory

Tags: c, memory

I need to **move memory**, as the source and destination may overlap. I don't know where is my error, one of them is that I can't use **size** as size for the char. The other ones I don't know

```
void mem_move(void* dest, void* src, unsigned size)
{
    char* d = dest, * s = src;
    char buff[size];
    char* b = buff;
    while (*b != '\0') {
        *b++ = *s++;
    }
    while (*b != '\0') {
        *d++ = *b++;
    }
}


void main()
{
    char buffer[] = "one two three  ";
    mem_move(buffer + 3, buffer, 10);
    char buffer2[] = "one two three  ";
    mem_move(buffer2, buffer2 + 3, 10);
}
```

Comment: You are making the false assumption that the memory block is zero-terminated.

Comment: Why not use the standard function `memmove`, which is robust, time-tested and highly optimized?  If you wish to re-implement it, you'll need to work out on which side your memory overlaps and arrange the move in the correct order (forward or reverse).

Comment: Are you aware that the C standard library offers the function [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove), which does exactly what you want? Is it your task to write such a function yourself?

Comment: If they overlap you can choose to copy in either forward of backward direction

Comment: Please post a full runnable code example, with any compiler error output or warnings, and expected program run results, and actual results.

Comment: The problem is that I need to write  the function myslef

Comment: 2) you forgot to reset `b` for the second loop.

Comment: 3) `b++ = s++;` ==> `*b++ = *s++;` and the other too.

Comment: Using a debugger and examining your pointer values after each loop holds the key to understanding the problem.

Comment: Your implementation does not exactly match the original `memmove`. This might not be a problem, but it seems unwise to deviate. The original uses one `const void *` argument and uses `size_t` instead of `unsigned`.

Comment: As always, a highly recommended exercise you can do with pen and paper is to draw some boxes representing memory, fill them with some values, then work through the cases for overlapping source/destination by hand to figure out how to copy the data non-destructively (_without_ an intermediate buffer).  Then take what you have discovered about how that must be done and implement it in C.

Comment: 4) assuming the data *is* 0-teminated, `while (*b != '\0')` ==> `while (*s != '\0')`

Comment: 5) don't use an automatic (stack) variable as the buffer.

Comment: You should also check whether `dest == src` and return immediately if that is the case.

Comment: @wildplasser: The C standard does not provide a portable feasible way to test whether two segments overlap. If `src` and `dest` do not point to bytes within a common object, then `src < dest` is not defined.