# Why am i getting this error code C2133 for visual studio 2022

Tags: c, visual-studio, char

This is the code and I want to know why am I getting errors when using unsigned size as the size of the arr **buff[size]**. I'm using **visual studio community edition 2022**. And the error is 'identifier': unknown size.

```
    void mem_move(void* dest, void* src, unsigned size)
{
    char* d = dest, * s = src;
    char buff[size];
    char* b = buff;
    while (*b <= size) {
        *b++ = *s++;
    }
    while (*b <= size){
        *d++ = *b++;
    }
    *d = *s;
}


void main()
{
    char buffer[] = "one two three  ";
    mem_move(buffer + 3, buffer, 10);
    char buffer2[] = "one two three  ";
    mem_move(buffer2, buffer2 + 3, 10);
}
```

Comment: Because the variable length array as in `char buff[size];` is not supported? The VLA is an optional language feature.

Comment: A follow-on from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239370/how-to-move-memory)? Note that `while (*b <= size)` is quite wrong. So is the concluding `*d = *s;` which (still) presumes your array was nul-terminated.